# Firefox scrollTop keeps the same relative position when adding content

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, scrollbar

I am building a chat.

When the user scrolls up and the `scrollTop` on the chat element reaches 3% of the `scrollHeight`, I load older messages.

It works perfectly fine on chrome and with a good connexion, you don't even notice the loading.

On Firefox, however, the scrollbar seems to want to keep the same "percentage" (relative) position when I add older messages.

As a result, when you reach the top 3%, older messages are loaded and the bar jumps up to stay at "3%" from the top. This makes you miss a bunch of the messages that were added and, on top of that, triggers the 3% loading of older messages once more.

Is there any way to prevent that and have it behave like on firefox?

I am using ReactJS and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by following this method: http://kirbysayshi.com/2013/08/19/maintaining-scroll-position-knockoutjs-list.html